# Обработка большого числа $_POST

Tags: post, php

Привет. Имеется БД с большим количеством колонок (а именно 36). Мне надо INSERT-тить туда данные, которые приходят с `$_POST` запросом. Среди данных которые пришли с `$_POST` запросом есть обязательные (без которых я не смогу записать их в БД, т.к есть в них необходимость) и не обязательные (т.е дополнительная информация и если не внесу их в БД ничего страшного).

Вопрос собственно в слудующем: как осуществить наиболее эффективную проверку всего, что пришло мне $_POST. Сейчас я делаю следующее:

cоздал 2 массива (один с обязательными наименованиями колонок БД `$base_key` и другой со всеми `$all_keys`)

foreach -ом прогоняю весь пришедший `$_POST` и проверяю ключ на наличие в указанных выше массивах, а значение на не `empty` и все что проходит валидацию я добавляю к `$into_sql`

```
foreach($_POST as $key=>$value){
    if(!empty($value) && in_array(strtoupper($key), $all_keys)) {
        if(array_key_exists(strtoupper($key), $base_keys)) {$base_counter++; //считает количество обязательных колонок}
            $into_sql .= "`".$key."`='".$this->db->safeSQL($value)."', ";
        }
    }

if($base_counter >= sizeOf($base_keys)){

    $this->db->query("INSERT INTO `some_table` ".$into_sql." SERVER_DATE=NOW()");       
 }
```

В принципе, все работает, как мне надо. Единственное, хотелось бы узнать у профессионалов насколько эффективен данный код с точки зрения безопасности, скорости и надежности и есть ли более правильный вариант (или варианты)?

**P.S** Я собрал все в одном массиве, в котором наименования колонок это ключи, а в качестве значения к обязательным ключам указал 'm', а к не обязательным 'n'.

```
if(array_key_exists(strtoupper($key), $allow_keys) && !empty($value)) {
   if($allow_keys[$key] == 'm') {$base_counter++;}
   $into_sql .= "`".$key."`='".$this->db->safeSQL($value)."', ";
}
```

Comment: подход нормальный, но я бы вытягивал обязательные и необязательные поля и сохранял бы в json файл ( типа cache ), если структура таблицы изменяется, естественно, его нужно обновлять. Соответственно, при необходимости, подымал бы массивы полей оттуда.

Просто ручками писать все поля это как-то долго :) Особенно если будут еще такие таблицы ( где будет много полей )

Comment: Спасибо, а разве чтение из json файла, будет быстрее, чем допустим из обычного массива, который у меня?

Comment: А я не писал что это будет быстрее, это будет умнее.

Т.е. если у вас завтра будет 10 таблиц по 200 полей вы тоже ручками массивы заполнять будете? Мне бы и 35 лениво было-бы заполнять :)

Comment: Ваш метод тоже отличный. Я обязательно задумаюсь. На хабре в принципе, тоже что-то в этом роде советовали. Лень это двигатель прогресса :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

а каково соотношение обязательных полеи и необязательных? Я к тому - что может нада прересмотреть структуру БД и вынести необязатльные параментры в отдельную или даже в отдельные таблицы - сгруппировав по смыслам параметры? ТО есть нада избегать пустоты таблиц -что может в конечном счете и на скорость повлиять

А зачем вы проверяете естьли переменная в общем масиве?

in_array(strtoupper($key), $all_keys))

тоесть возможно ситуация что с данными могут и  ненужные данные прийти ?

Понятно - чтоб небаловались- тоже хорошо.
Тогда я бы вам посоветовал сначала проверить ключь в массиве собязательными ключами - если да то клеим запрос, если етого ключа нет - то тогда проверяем в массиве с необязательными ключами.

Хотя даже наверно вам нада сделать 2 массива - один с обязательными полями, а другой с необязательными. А то сейчас у вас один массив содержит и другой массив. И тогда можно проверять в любом порядке

Да у вас сейчас 2 массива - один со всеми полями таблицы а другой с обязательными. Я вам предлагаю 1 массим с обязательными полями а другой не с обязательными.

Comment: Дело в том, что система которая посылает мне $_POST, мною не регулируется и в зависимости от объястоятельств может посылать данные содержащие как обязательные, так и не обязательные данные.

Comment: in_array на всякий случай, вдруг кто-то решит побаловаться и будет слать различные запросы.

Comment: Так у меня 2 массива :) "cоздал 2 массива (один с обязательными наименованиями колонок БД $base_key и другой со всеми $all_keys)"

Comment: А ясненько. Я сделал несколько иначе. Но именно ваш совет натолкнул меня на эту мысль. Я собрал все в одном массиве, в котором наименования колонок это ключи, а в качестве значения к обязательным ключам указал 'm', а к не обязательным 'n'. Проапдейтил свой вопрос.